# Properly split an MPEG-1 Layer 3 for streaming server

Tags: javascript, mp3, audio-streaming, mpeg

I'm working on a music streaming server. Right now i want to send MP3 file in chunks from the server to the client (through the http-range request/response). My client successfully decode the response data and play the music chunk after chunk (fixed byte size) , but between each chunk there is a **stutter sound** (short but noticeable).

The encoding version of the MP3 file is MPEG-1 and layer 3. I read about MP3 format [at this article](https://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html), i noticed that in layer 3 frames are not independent (called bit/byte reservoir) and they specifically said:

> In the worst case, 9 input frames may be needed before being able to decode one single frame

The reason i use http-range request is because after checking out **Spotify** network transfer (Chrome dev-tool), i copy their technique for requesting partial content. The byte length they request is approximately 166000, but not fixed (sometime 166287, 16682... bytes)

*Question:*

Does **Spotify** split their file in approximate (not fixed) size chunk?

If so, how do i properly split this MPEG-1 Layer 3 file correctly for streaming?

Comment: First off, yes, you should split on frame boundaries. Because clients may join a stream at any point in time. Second, the gaps may be unrelated. How are you playing the files back? Finally, why not just use HLS or DASH instead of trying to reinvent this?

Comment: Right now, i'm using javascript on the client-side to playback the audio. I use "AudioContext" class and "decodeAudioData" method to decode each chunk and put the decoded chunk into a "AudioBufferSourceNode" to start/play that audio chunk.
What do you mean by "the gaps may be unrelated"?

Comment: I mean that if the decoder is being reset every chunk, there will be audio artifacts on chunk boundaries regardless of where it is split. I highly recommend you use Media source extensions instead of this approach. It’s way less code, and designed to do exactly this.

Comment: The "AudioContext" which contains the "decodeAudioData" method is only created once. Also, i have tried this approach with different back-end implementation, i decoded the mp3 file to PCM format and send a fixed number of frames to client to play the audio, the playback is very smooth.
I will definitely check out the MediaSource extension, thanks for letting me know different approaches.

Comment: Is MP3 absolutely required or can you use Opus audio files instead?

Comment: @AnthumChris, actually no, just any formats that can be played from web and mobile.

Answer (score 1):

> Right now, i'm using javascript on the client-side to playback the audio. I use "AudioContext" class and "decodeAudioData" method to decode each chunk

As @szatmary points out, this is the problem.  You're treating these chunks as if they're totally independent, but they aren't.  This causes the glitches to occur.

What you need to do is decode as you go, and add data to the end of that buffer that you're decoding.  [MediaSource Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API) is the prescribed way way to do this.  MSE gives you control over how you're fetching that data, so if you want to fetch it with Range requests, you can.

I think a better suggestion though is just to let the browser handle it.  Simply set the `src` attribute of an Audio element and let it play.  The browser is smart enough to make its own range requests, and will also fallback to regular requests if needed.  This allows the browser to also handle flow control.  You don't need to do any extra work, and you'll end up with a more optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I also want to control the maximum number of bytes requested by the client on the server side, so i think i gonna give MediaSource a try (this is the first time i knew about this).

Comment: You can still control the data you send from the server without MediaSource.

Comment: So i manage to use MediaSource to stream audio chunk by chunk, finally.There's one small thing i want to ask is about the SourceBuffer. Right now i'm using one SourceBuffer to hold all of the segment, i want to ask when to use multiple SourceBuffer, one seem to be working fine ?

Answer (score 1):

Spotify uses [Encrypted Media Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Encrypted_Media_Extensions_API).  Once the file header is read, the remaining chunks are fed via HTTP `Range` requests during seeking or normal playback.

Consider abandoning MP3 (very old) all together in favor of [64-kbit Opus files](https://opus-codec.org/comparison/).  MSE can play `audio/webm codecs=opus` files but cannot currently play `audio/ogg` files.  If you need to play Ogg Opus files, you could bypass MSE and use WebAssembly with the Web Audio API, but you'll need to manually throttle the decoding and output buffers to be memory-efficient.  You'll have more control but the coding is more complicated.

See chunk decoding examples at https://fetch-stream-audio.anthum.com/